# Get parent when using accepts_nested_attributes_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

When receiving:

```
{
   parent:{
      children_attributes:[
        {child1}, {child2}
      ]
   }
}
```

And `child1` instance is about to be created, I don't have `parent_id` set. I suppose this is set in save time.

How can I handle this to say something like:

```
class Child < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent
  before_save :do_something

  def do_something
    # access parent here
    # I can't, since parent_id is nil yet
  end
end
```

## Update to be more clear

```
class Parent <  ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :children
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :children
end
```

## Update 2

I tried this from related questions:

```
class Parent <  ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :children, inverse_of: :parent
end
```

But same issue.

## Update 3 according comment

I tried this

```
class Parent
  before_save :save_children
  attr_accessor :children_attributes

  def save_children
    children_attributes.all? do |k, attrs|
      # tried different things here, this one is the one I expected to work the most 
      child = Child.new attrs.merge(parent_id: id)
      child.save
    end
  end
```

I added parent_id to child attr_accessible call.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

The cause of this problem for me was the validation of the presence of the parent in the child class.

I essentially removed this line from the Child object and it works.

```ruby
validates :parent, presence: true
```

From what I've found, however, the correct way to resolve this is the use of the `inverse_of` parameter. If you add this to the `has_many` of the parent and the `belongs_to` of the child, you should be good to go.

In the parent:

```
has_many :child, inverse_of: :parent
```

In the child:

```
belongs_to :parent, inverse_of: :child
```

Comment: How do you access the parent from within the child? I have `self.parent` inside the child but got `nil`.

Comment: @W.M. Are you using the actual name of the class? `:parent` was just used as an example for a parent class' name.

Answer (score 1):

Set `inverse_of: :model_name` in has_many declaration in your model where model_name is your 'parent' model.

For example: `has_many :product_items, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :product`

Answer (score 0):

In your model, you should be able to reference the parent like this:

```
self.parent_class
```

So for example, if a product have many parts, in your parts model (part.rb) you can refer to an attribute of the product like this:

```
self.product.id
```

That would return the id of the product that is the parent of the part. You can obviously reference any attribute of the parent like this.

This should work in your before_save callback in the child model.

Also, you shouldn't need the "inverse_of: :parent" that you included in your code above for this to work.

And to answer your question about when the parent id is added, that should be automatically passed in the params from your form to your controller if your form is set up correctly.

Comment: I will sne did from for to see what happens, but I have have set id with child.parent_id = id inside parent, and it is not detected.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not following your comment.  Can you explain further or post your code as an update?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do in the code you posted in update 3?  It seems like you are trying to do some things that Rails should do automatically, like saving both the parent and child records through nested attributes (without you having to use the before_save callback).  Do you have a form through which you are inputting data for the parent and child models in a view template?  Please post that and your controller and I'll be able to tell you what to change.

Comment: I found my real problem, is a timing problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17959065/rename-image-paperclip-using-associated-model

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not help with your issue: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#association-callbacks

Association callbacks don't work with `belongs_to`, but does work well with `has_many`.

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :children, before_add: :do_something

  def do_something(child)
    # self.id = 1
    # child.parent_id = 1
  end
end

# parent1 = Parent.find(1)
# parent1.children.create(...)
```

---

Comment: tried that, not working,maybe I have something not correctly configured. another thing is that `parent.children.build` correctly sets `parent_id` on `child` but just in console, server does not do it.

Comment: when I used `before_add` it did not run method I passed there, I tried printing something in server console, message did not appear.

Comment: I found my problem I will post it as another question.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to handle this is to override the `child_attributes(attributes)` method added to the parent model.

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

You can set the parent association on the child here

```
def child_attributes(attributes)
  self.child = Child.new(attributes.merge(parent: self))
end
```

This allows you to reference the parent from the child on `new`