# Rename image using associated model - Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

## Code

In my image model:

```
has_attached_file :pic
before_post_process :rename_pic
before_save ->{ p 'before_save ----------------' }
after_post_process ->{ p 'after_post_process --------------' }

  def rename_pic
    p 'en imagen'
    p self
    p 'en imagen'
  end
```

In service that has many images:

```
  # don't use accepts_nested_attributes_for
  before_save :create_images
  attr_accessor :images_attributes

  def create_images
    # images_attributes example value: { "0"=> {img_attrs}, "1" => {img_attrs1} } 
    images_attributes.all? do |k, image_attrs|
      if image_attrs.delete(:_destroy) == "false"
        p 'asd'
        image = Image.new image_attrs.merge(service_id: id)
        p image.service
        p image.service_id
        image.save
      end
    end
  end
```

This is the output I get:

```
"asd"
"en imagen"
#<Image id: nil, service_id: nil, pic_file_name: "Screen_Shot_2013-04-07_at_5.18.03_PM.png", pic_content_type: "image/png", pic_file_size: 16041, pic_updated_at: "2013-07-30 22:58:46", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, user_id: nil>
"en imagen"
G"after_post_process --------------"
#<Service id: 427, event_id: nil, min_capacity: nil, max_capacity: nil, price: #<BigDecimal:7fb6e9d73d48,'0.0',9(18)>, image_path: nil, name: "Super Franks", desc: "zxc", created_at: "2013-05-12 19:01:54", updated_at: "2013-07-30 19:32:48", address: "pasadena", longitude: 77.225, latitude: 28.6353, gmaps: true, city: "san francisco", state: "california", country_id: "472", tags: "Banquet", created_by: 22, avg_rating: #<BigDecimal:7fb6efdbcf10,'0.0',9(18)>, views: 27, zip_code: "", address2: "", price_unit: "", category_id: 3, featured: true, publish: true, slug: "banquet-super-franks", discount: nil, currency_code: "USD", video_url: "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A3pIrBZQJvE", short_description: "">
427
"before_save ----------------"
```

## Problem

When calling

```
image = Image.new image_attrs.merge(service_id: id)
```

Paperclips seems to start processing, and then set service_id.

So when I try to use `service` inside `rename_pic` service is `nil`.

Any ideas on how to handle this?

Answer (score 2):

This solved my problem, I changed:

```
before_post_process :rename_pic
```

to:

```
before_create :rename_pic
```

and this is rename_pic, for the record:

```
def rename_pic
  extension = File.extname(pic_file_name).downcase
  self.pic.instance_write :file_name,
    "#{service.hyphenated_for_seo}#{extension}"
end
```

where `service` `has_many` `images`, and `image` `belongs_to` `service`.

Answer (score 0):

Be carefull with the fix of @juanpastas, because if you change `before_post_process` to `before_create`, it will only run when you create your image, and **not when you update it**. To have the callback still run on update, do this:

```
class YourImage
  has_attached_file :pic

  # use both callbacks
  before_create                     :rename_pic
  before_post_process               :rename_pic

  def rename_pic
    # assotiated_object is the association used to get pic_file_name
    return if self.assotiated_object.nil?

    extension = File.extname(pic_file_name).downcase
    self.pic.instance_write :file_name,
      "#{service.hyphenated_for_seo}#{extension}"
  end
end
```

Comment: hmmm, I don't re,eber this, why before_save does not work to run callback when updating too?

Comment: @juanpastas The callback `before_save` is not called at all when saving the attachment. So you have to use `before_create`

Comment: ok, thanks, it seems incoherent before_save is not called when saving attachment though, do you know the reason?